# Declaring a variable inside an equality operation possible?

Tags: c#

Very quick question - whilst the following is possible in C#:

```
var a = new []{"hello"};
string[] b;
if ((b=a)!=null) { ... }
```

the following is not:

```
var a = new []{"hello"};
if ((string[] b=a)!=null) { ... }
```

Just wanted to confirm that I wasnt doing anything wrong in the second example and something along those lines are not possible. (In the similiar way aspects from the second example might be posible inside a `using()`.

Comment: by "not possible", do you mean won't compile or, throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, since in c# variable declaration is a 'statement', not an expression. Statements do not yield a value, therefore I do not think you can use it in a expression.

But the assignment, which you use in the <strike>second</strike> first form is an 'expression' which yield a result (value of a in this case), which can be used in another expression with an operator.

More context from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664741%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It specifically mentions:

> A declaration-statement declares a local variable or constant.
>   Declaration statements are permitted in blocks, but are not permitted
>   as embedded statements.

So it looks more like a 'language restriction' more than 'lack of a return value', although that (lack of return values of statements) must have influenced such a restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct, you *can not* do like that.

The reason is simply that the *declaration* of the variable can not be a part of *conditional statement*, also because, even if it would be possible, the `variable` will be allocated either condition validate to `true` or validates to `false`.  Check an `IL` and you will see.

So from the clear and understandable code point of view, it's correct to pretend from the coder to write

```
string[] b;
if ((b=a)!=null) { ... }
```

Comment: For clear code I'd prefer `string[] b = a; if(b != null)...` so that the `if` condition has no side-effects.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: well this goes behind the discussion, cause I can call also the computation inside condition check, call a function, but *at least declaraiton* compiler *can* force me put out, the rest is a matter of test...

Answer (score 1):

Wait,

To simplify your question.

You can do,

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var c = a = b;
```

but you can't do,

```
var x = 0;
var x = var y = 1;
```

this seems obvious.

The assign of a value returns the assigned value. The instantiation or initialisation of a variable does not.

However, you do allude to cases where we can instantiate in a block declaration.

```
using(var x = new SomeIDisposable(...

foreach(var y in SomeIEnumerable...
```

There are certainly others. These are essentially syntactic sugar. The designers of c# have corrupted its semantic purity to make it easier to use. I assume they have not done this generally, for all instantiations, because in thier opinion, it leads to messy code.